# PHP - how to randomly get something from array

Tags: php, arrays

how can i get something randomly from a array for example i have this array I want to grab one of those lines randomly how can I do that using PHP?

```
 $quizes = array(
        '3-1' => '2',
        '4+4' => '8',
        '7-5' => '2',
        '4+2' => '6',
        '9-3' => '6',
        '1+2' => '3',
        '9+9' => '18',
        '3+2' => '5',
        '2*3' => '6',
        '5*3' => '15',
        '6+6' => '12',
        '3+4' => '7',
        '7-4' => '3',
        '6+2' => '8',
        '3*2' => '6',
        '7+6' => '13',
        '1+1' => '2',
        '4*4' => '16',
        '10-3' => '7'
    );
```

**What i have tried**

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($quizes, 2);
echo $quizes[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $quizes[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
```

but this only returns results such as 2 7, 15 2, 3 2 and more

Please help thank you

Comment: What do you want it to return?

Comment: You can get the key using `echo $rand_keys[0];`

Comment: I hope my answer is what you wanted, but for future, in your question you should precise what is expected output, so we could answer you faster and better.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i want it to return on of the rows with the first part and the second part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are getting exactly what you are asking for - value that belongs to randomly chosen key. 
To get `key => value` pair execute:

```
echo $rand_keys[0] . " => " . $quizes[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
```

Of course you can format output however you'd like to.

Answer (score 1):

You can randomize the array order and take the first element. The code would look like this:

```
shuffle($quizes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of the "rows" in your code is actually two parts: a key and its corresponding value. For example, in the first row `'3-1'` is the key and `'2'` is its value. The `=>` operator indicates this relationship.

The `array_rand` function you used will return a random key (or set of keys, if you specify the second parameter) from your array.

```
$key = array_rand($quizes);    // returns a random key e.g. '3-1'
```

Then you can use that key to get the corresponding value,

```
$value = $quizes[$key];        // returns the value that matches $key
```

There are various ways to output them from that point. If you want it to look kind of like it does in the code, you can use

```
echo "$key => $value";
```